# Как преобразовать url с помощью mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod_rewrite, php

```
RewriteRule ^files/category_(.*)/page_(.*)\.html$ files/index.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Должно получится что-то типа этого `www.www.com/files/category_10/page_1/` или так на крайний случай `www.www.com/files/category_10-page_1/`

Как правильно это записать, помогите.

Answer (score 1):

.html на конце ссылки, я так понимаю, лишний. (.*) - менее эффективно использовать, если подстановок несколько. Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteRule ^files/category_([^/]+)/page_([^/]+)/?$ files/index.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

На входе передаем `/files/category_10/page_1/` на выходе `files/index.php?cat=10&page=1`

Comment: не работает стили и скрипты перестают работать

Comment: для стилей и скриптов нужно свое правило написать.

Answer (score 0):

Возможная причина: первая группа () это $1, вторая группа () это уже $2

Comment: изменил все равно не работает

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой сервис для генерации ЧПУ. [GenerateIt](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/)