# Вопрос по .htaccess - преобразование url (mod_rewrite и все такое)

Tags: apache, url, mod_rewrite, php

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно составить `.htaccess`.

У меня вот такого вида ссылки:

```
http://zzz.net/index.php?sort=id&q=zzz
http://zzz.net/index.php?sort=rating&q=zzz
http://zzz.net/index.php?sort=date&q=zzz
http://zzz.net/index.php?sort=view&q=zzz
http://zzz.net/index.php?sort=comment&q=zzz
http://zzz.net/index.php?category=vbs
http://zzz.net/?post=17
http://zzz.net/?p=1
http://zzz.net/?p=1&sort=rating
http://zzz.net/?p=1&sort=date
http://zzz.net/?p=1&sort=view
http://zzz.net/?p=1&sort=comment
http://zzz.net/index.php?q=%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB
http://zzz.net/index.php?p=1&q=%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB
http://zzz.net/index.php?sort=id&q=%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB
http://zzz.net/index.php?sort=rating&q=%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB
http://zzz.net/index.php?p=1&sort=rating&q=%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB
http://zzz.net/index.php?p=1&sort=date&q=%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB
http://zzz.net/index.php?p=1&sort=view&q=%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB
http://zzz.net/index.php?p=1&sort=comment&q=%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB
```

Хочу сделать их вида:

```
http://zzz.net/p/1/sort/comment/q/%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB
```

Все запросы у меня идут к файлу `index.php`, а он, в свою очередь, выдает тот или иной шаблон.

Раньше не работал с `mod_rewrite`, поэтому не знаю, как правильно организовать.

Если у вас есть любые примеры, пишите их тут, все пригодятся.

А можно ли обойтись без `mod_rewrite` и генерировать с помощью `php`?

В общемб у меня очень много вопросов. Помогите, пожалуйста, ответить хотя бы на часть из них :)

Answer (score 5):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\$ /index.php?p=$1&sort=$2&q=$3 [L]
```

На начальном этапе воспользуйтесь [генератором](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/).
В дальнейшем, если возникнут [конкретные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/120202/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-index-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-get-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81) [вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/84024/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-url-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-mod_rewrite), [пишите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/81391/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%88-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5-url-mod_rewrite).

Comment: Отдельное спасибо за ссылки!